# Recyclerview view width is not aligned

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on the recycler view, but I face one problem: the item alignment is not correct. How can I solve this problem?

I need the items to match the parent's width.

#### What I want

[image]

#### Problem

[image]

Code :-
Adapter -
class CancelBookingAdapter(
val data: List<CancelReasonsResponse.Data>,
val callBack: CancelBookingCallBack
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CancelBookingAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

```
var selectedPosition = -1
var comments = ""

class ViewHolder(val binding: CancelAdapterBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = CancelAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),null,false)
    val lp = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
enter code here
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.apply {
        tvReasonText.text = data[position].title

        if (selectedPosition == -1) {
            comments = ""
        }else {
            comments = data[position].title
        }

        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            llReason.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_box)
        }else {
            llReason.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cancel_outline)
        }

        llReason.setOnClickListener {
            selectedPosition = holder.adapterPosition
            callBack.onClickCheckBox(data[position].id, comments)
            selectedPosition = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}
```

}

interface CancelBookingCallBack {
fun onClickCheckBox(reasonId: Int, comment: String)
}

Item XML -

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/llReason"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_outline"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReasonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/space_grotesk_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel_booking"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder()`, you need to pass the `parent` parameter in the `inflate()` call, instead of `null`: `CancelAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

*android:layout_width="match_parent"*

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReasonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/space_grotesk_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel_booking"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: its not working bro i am using bottom sheet maybe thats why its not working.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change and why? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75459393/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can maximize the width.

> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> or
> android:layout_width="0dp"

this code will help you to center the text

> android:textAlignment="center"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReasonText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/space_grotesk_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel_booking"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```